# Checklist e Dialog com arquivo externo - Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Preciso utilizar o `Dialog` fazendo um **Checklist** de um arquivo externo, fiz até agora o seguinte:

```
dialog --stdout --checklist "Contas de e-mail: " 0 0 0 \
while read line
do
$line "" on \
done < contasemail.txt
```

Porém estou tendo como retorno a seguinte mensagem de erro, **que espera ter as informações do checklist**

Comment: Não tenho certeza do que precisas mas testa isto que encontrei neste link http://aurelio.net/shell/dialog/:
dialog --stdout --title 'Lista de emails' \
       --checklist "Contas de e-mail: "   \
    0 0 0                              \
while read line
do
$line "" on \
done < contasemail.txt

Comment: @ClaudioLopes, vou verificar aqui e te dou um retorno

Comment: Qual é o conteudo do arquivo `contasemail.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contasemail.txt`:

```
fulano@gmail.com
beltrano@microsoft.com
silva@uol.com.br
maria@gmail.com
joao@microsoft.com
jose@uol.com.br
```

`checklist.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
tags=()

while read -r tag;
do
    tags+=("${tag} off")
done < "$filename"

emails=$(dialog --stdout --no-items --checklist "Contas de e-mail:" 20 50 ${#tags[@]} ${tags[@]})
```

Teste:

```
$ ./checklist.sh contasemail.txt
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]