# Usar o comando xargs como entrada de um arquivo para popular Xdialog --radiolist

Tags: linux, bash, dialog, dinâmico

A questão aqui é muito simples!

Aqui está uma variável:

```
arquivo="\"Item 1\" 'A' off \"Item 2\" 'B' off \"Item 3\" 'C' off \"Item 4\" 'D' off \"Item 5\" 'E' off \"Item 6\" 'F' off"
```

Observe que no comprimento da variável contém as opções para cada botão de verificação.

As aspas devem ser escapadas assim:

> `\"Item 1\"`

Abaixo **esta um trecho que precisa** de uma lista **de verificação de comprimento**:

```
echo $arquivo | xargs Xdialog --stdout --separate-output --radiolist 'Seu Texto Aqui' 0 0 0
```

**RESULTADO:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Em vez de escrever as opções em uma variável para **popular de modo dinâmico** a `Xdialog`, preciso usar um arquivo como entrada para populacionar.

**EXEMPLO:**

```
cat /tmp/arquivo.txt | xargs Xdialog --stdout --separate-output --radiolist 'Seu Texto Aqui' 0 0 0
```

**ARQUIVO:**

```
\"Item 1\"  'A'     off
\"Item 2\"  'B'     off
\"Item 3\"  'C'     off
\"Item 4\"  'D'     off
\"Item 5\"  'E'     off
\"Item 6\"  'F'     off
```

**PRINT SCREEN:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No *manual* do `xargs`, encontrei esta informação que acho ser a solução para a pergunta:

```
$ man xargs
...
       --arg-file=arquivo
       -a arquivo

              Leia itens do arquivo em vez da entrada padrão. Se você usar isso
              opção, stdin permanece inalterado quando os comandos são executados. De outros-
              sábio, stdin é redirecionado de /dev/null.
...
```

Tentei implementar isso .. mas não funcionou.

> Referências
>
> 1- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/dialog-radiolist-with-list-from-file-to-choose-not-working-930774/
>
> 2- [Checklist e Dialog com arquivo externo - Shell Script](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240619/checklist-e-dialog-com-arquivo-externo-shell-script)
>
> 3- https://aurelio.net/shell/dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos a solução:

**ARQUIVO:**

> O grande problema aqui é que como o nome tem espaços em branco, cada palavra é vista como um parâmetro e bagunça o menu. A solução é colocar o nome entre \"aspas escapadas\" e usar o `eval` para executar o comando.

```
\"Item 1\"  'A'     off
\"Item 2\"  'B'     off
\"Item 3\"  'C'     off
\"Item 4\"  'D'     off
\"Item 5\"  'E'     off
\"Item 6\"  'F'     off
```

**PASSO-A-PASSO**

```
$ arquivo=`cat /tmp/arquivo.txt`

$ eval echo $arquivo | xargs Xdialog --stdout --separate-output --radiolist 'Seu Texto Aqui' 0 0 0
```

**PRINT DO RESULTADO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> **IMPORTANTE!** - "Neste contexto, **é preciso criar uma variável** com o comando `cat` para utilizar com `eval`, seguido do `echo` para ele enxergar o conteúdo da *variável* `$arquivo` que passará como parâmetro para o *shell*. Que por sua vez executa os comandos `xargs` que lê o *stdin* para o `Xdialog` ou `dialog`."

---

**Basicamente é isso que cada um desses comando faz:**

- O principal uso do `cat` é ler conteúdo de arquivos.
- O `eval` **combina argumentos em uma única string** e os **usa como uma entrada para o *shell*** e executa os comandos.
- O comando `echo` além de mostrar mensagens na tela, serve para ver o valor de *variáveis* do sistema ou que você criar.
- O comando `xargs` é utilizado para construir e executar linhas de comandos no Linux. É comum precisarmos passar uma lista de itens para um comando que é maior do que o *shell* pode trabalhar. O comando `xargs` pode ser utilizado para efetuar uma divisão dessa lista em sub-listas menores, e passar os argumentos ao comando requisitado (no nosso caso é o - `Xdialog` ou `dialog`), em partes.